# Product of two Toeplitz matrices?

Tags: performance, algorithm, matrix, fft, matrix-multiplication

The `O(n log n)` algorithm for the product of a Toeplitz matrix and a vector of the correct length is well-known: put it in a circulant matrix, multiply it by the vector (and subsequent zeroes), and return the top `n` elements of the product.

I'm finding trouble finding the best (time-wise) algorithm for multiplying two Toeplitz matrices of the same size.

Can anyone give me an algorithm for this?

Comment: The product of Toeplitz matrices is not necessarily Toeplitz. How is the output to be represented?

Comment: As an nxn matrix, seeing as there's no other representation that would display all the relevant data in this case. I'm not asking for an algorithm that runs faster than `O(n^2)`, I am merely wondering if there is a faster algorithm than the standard matrix multiplication routine in this case.

Comment: Note that the product of two circulant matrices is circulant. I wonder if there's a algorithm faster than O(n^2) to calculate the product of two circulant matrices, both expressed as vectors.

Comment: @nneonneo There's an O(n log n)-time algorithm -- multiply the first matrix by one row of the second and take n different rotations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an O(n^2)-time algorithm.

To compute one of the diagonals of the product matrix, we need to compute dot products over length-n windows of length-(2n-1) lists that are sliding in lockstep. The difference between two successive entries can be computed in time O(1).

For example, consider the product of

```
e f g h i    o p q r s
d e f g h    m o p q r
c d e f g    l m o p q
b c d e f    k l m o p
a b c d e    j k l m o
```

The 1,1 entry is `eo + fm + gl + hk + ij`. The 2,2 entry is `dp + eo + fm + gl + hk`, or the 1,1 entry minus `ij` plus `dp`. The 3,3 entry is `cq + dp + eo + fm + gl`, or the 2,2 entry minus `hk` plus `cq`. The 4,4 entry is `br + cq + dp + eo + fm`, etc.

If you implement this in floating point, be mindful of [catastrophic cancellation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance).

Comment: Can you please expand on this? I don't understand what you mean by sliding in lock step, but I do see the pattern you're trying to show.

Comment: @Jonathan I guess another way to say it is that we can multiply the lists pointwise and then the elements of the diagonal are sums of n consecutive elements of the products list.

Comment: Is there a way to mathematically represent that?

Comment: @Jonathan Convolution with an all-ones vector?